# Are there sequences with the property: If $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_{n}=s$ then $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} 1/a_{n}=1/s$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

If $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_{n}=s$$ then $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{1}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{s}$$

I assume it is online possible for an alternating series if possible at all but I have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: If a series is convergent then $a_n\to 0$. It is not possible then to get $\frac 1{a_n}\to 0$ too.

Comment: oh god of course

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. If the first one converge to $s$, hence $\lim a_n = 0$ while for the second one $\lim a_{n} \neq 0$ which implies the series doesn't converge.